# G++ unresolved identifier, cannot find linker error

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I'm not sure if this is an error in my makefile, header, or source, but it looks like all the relevant pieces of code should link up nicely so I can use functions from one C++ file inside another, but I'm running into a brick wall. Here's a simplified version of what I'm working with:

common.h:

```
//common.h
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

int foo();
#endif
```

common.cc:

```
//common.cc
#include "common.h"

int main(){
    int z = foo();
    return 0;
}//main

int foo(){
    int x = 5;
    int y = 7;
    return x + y;
}//foo
```

test.cc:

```
//test.cc

#include "common.h"

int main(){
    return foo();
}
```

And the makefile (sorry, it's a bit more complex, to better reflect how my overall project is operating):

```
TARGETS = common test
FLAGS = -lpthread
DEPS = common.h

all: $(TARGETS)

common: common.cc $(DEPS)
    g++ $^ $(FLAGS) -g -o $@

test: test.cc $(DEPS)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $^ -g -o $@

clean::
    rm -fv $(TARGETS) *~
```

The compiler seems happy compiling common.cc, but runs into an unresolved identifier error on test.cc:

> g++ -lpthread test.cc common.h -g -o test
>
> /tmp/ccMwBGAj.o: In function `main':
>
> /home/...../test.cc:6: undefined reference to `foo()'

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: You are compiling a header file `common.h ` - you should be compiling a .cc file. Also, names of libraries should be the last things on the compiler command line.

Comment: Not to ask for too much guidance, @NeilButterworth, but how would I switch things around from compiling common.h into compiling common.cc?

Comment: @TaylorNelms In the make file: `DEPS = common.h` This makes it compile `test.cc` and `common.h`. Compiling `common.h` is not useful (there are not definitions in there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that when you try to build `test`, the only files you use are `test.cc` and `common.h`. The code in `test.cc` calls the function `foo()`, but that function is not defined in either of those files; it is defined in `common.cc`, which was not invited. And if you try to fix that by adding `common.cc` or `common.o` to the recipe, you'll run into more trouble, because `common.cc` contains a definition of `main()`, and so does `test.cc`, and there can be only one.

If you want to use `foo()` with other versions of `main()`, you should not put a `main()` in `common.cc`.

Now for the makefile recipe:

```
test: test.cc $(DEPS)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $^ -g -o $@
```

This expands to:

```
test: test.cc common.h
    g++ -lpthread test.cc common.h -g -o test
```

Which is incorrect, as @NeilButterworth has pointed out. You could do this:

```
test: test.cc common.cc
    g++ test.cc common.cc -lpthread -g -o test
```

which can be written as:

```
test: test.cc common.cc
    g++ $^ $(FLAGS) -g -o $@
```

But that can fail to rebuild when `common.h` is changed, and when it does rebuild it can recompile a source that *hasn't* changed. A better approach is:

```
common.o: common.cc $(DEPS)
    g++ -c $< -g -o $@

test.o: test.cc $(DEPS)
    g++ -c $< -g -o $@

common: common.o
    g++ $^ $(FLAGS) -o $@

test: test.o common.o
    g++ $^ $(FLAGS) -o $@
```

And further improvement is possible, once you have this much working.